# In Highcharts, is it possible to add a border to the legend symbol?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, data-visualization

In highcharts, to configure the legend symbol (the small square in front of each legend item), there are four properties can be configured:
`symbolHeight, symbolPadding, symbolRadius, symbolWidth`.
Is it possible to add some extra properties to it? Like `borderWidth, borderColor...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`symbolHeight`, `symbolPadding`, `symbolRadius`, and `symbolWidth` are merely used to adjust the **size** and **placement** of the symbols in the legend. To further change the appearance of these symbols, you should look at the options for `series.marker.symbol` instead (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.marker.symbol).

There's a demo fiddle the Highcharts team created that shows you a bunch of options for marker symbols, each of which shows up in the legend as well: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/

Hopefully, one of these options should be suitable for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is a great answer!

Comment: You're very welcome! I'm glad this was helpful for you.